# NHibenate: Is there a way to create a one to many bidirectional relationship with composite keys?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to setup a bidirectional one-to-many relationship in NHibernate on 2 classes both with composite keys that overlap.
Another difficulty is that I can't just edit the SQL tables to for example add a proper ID.

This is probably an easy question but i can't find the answer anywhere.

I've got the HasMany down, as far as i can see. But I'm stuck with the HasOne. Also tried with Reference.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.A)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.B)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.C);
        Map(x => x.Data);
        HasMany(x => x.Children)
                .KeyColumn("A")
                .KeyColumn("B")
                .KeyColumn("C");
    }
}
public class ChildMap : ClassMap<Child>
{
    public ChildMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.A)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.B)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.C)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.D);
        Map(x => x.Data);
        HasOne(x => x.Parent);
        // also tried
        //References<Parent>(x => x.Parent)
                //.Columns("A", "B", "C");
    }
}
```

The error i get now is: 
NHibernate.FKUnmatchingColumnsException: 'Foreign key (FK_3346D8AD:Child [C])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Parent [A, B, C])'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children)
    .KeyColumn("A")
    .KeyColumn("B")
    .KeyColumn("C");
```

What it should be:

```
HasMany(x => x.Children)
    .KeyColumns.AddRange("A", "B", "C");
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know fluent nhibernate but in general regarding your `Child.Parent` property mapping - one-to-one (`HasOne`) is not the right mapping here. One-to-one mapping will work only when `Id` is the same for both entities. So it should be [A, B, C] for both `Child` and `Parent`.

But many-to-one mapping (`References`) should work - you just need to mark all referenced columns or property as readonly (you need to find fluent equivalent of `insert="false" update="false"` in hbm.xml) as those columns are already part of you Id mapping. In hbm.xml the mapping would look like:

```xml
<many-to-one name="Parent" insert="false" update="false" not-null="true">
    <column name="A"/>
    <column name="B"/>
    <column name="C"/>
</many-to-one>
```

So in fluent nhibernate it should look something like:

```
References<Parent>(x => x.Parent).Columns("A", "B", "C")
//Not sure if it exists
.Readonly(); 
//Or something like this
.Insert(false).Update(false);
```